# Place holder (First Page) of PDF files in android

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf

I want to show first page of multi page PDF file on imageview and open PDF file on imageView click.

I'm calling an api and getting PDF files urls as response. Users can upload PDF files and view uploaded files.

(Whatsapp also create placeholder of the pdf, just like that)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to support API > 21 then you can use `PdfRenderer` like this.

```
// create a new renderer
 PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());

 // let us just render all pages
 final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
 for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
     Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

     // say we render for showing on the screen
     page.render(mBitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

     // do stuff with the bitmap

     // close the page
     page.close();
 }

 // close the renderer
 renderer.close();
```

For more info have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer